# c# htmlagilitypack parse first link from div with class?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse the first link in the html code below `/search?id=3`

```
<div class="brs_col">
  <p>
    <a href="/search?id=3">
      <b>
        vastu shastra
      </b>
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="/search?id=1">
      <b>
        bygga
      </b>
      bastu
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I've tried to select it with the following XPATH, but cant seem to get any of them to work:

```
//div[@class='brs_col']//p//a[@href]
//div[@class='brs_col']//p[0]//a[@href]
//div[@class='brs_col']//p//a[0][@href]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Even if it's not optimized, the first one `//div[@class='brs_col']//p//a[@href]` should work. Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"<div class=""brs_col"">
                  <p><a href=""/search?id=3""><b>vastu shastra</b></a></p>
                  <p><a href=""/search?id=1""><b>bygga</b>bastu</a></p>
                </div>");
var hrefValue = doc.DocumentNode
                   .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='brs_col']/p/a")
                   .Attributes["href"]
                   .Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

This if you sure that is the first url in the whole HTML document:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a").Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Or this if you sure that is the first ulr in the class brs_col

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='brs_col']//a").Attributes["href"].Value;
```